# How to repair a long crack in my epoxy covered garage floor?

Tags: concrete, garage, epoxy

Last summer we decided to get our garage floor coated with epoxy.

We had a section that was cracked (see first photo) and hired a concrete guy to repair it (see second photo). He put rebar every 16" to join the old and new concrete.

We waited a month for it to cure, then we had the epoxy floor installed by a professional.

The next spring, we noticed a long crack along the joint of the new/old concrete.

I am nervous that if we don't fix that crack, water will get under the epoxy and ruin the coating.

My questions:

- Does it seem like the initial repair to the concrete was done poorly?
  Or is cracking at the joint normal?
- Does anyone know how to fix the
  crack without completely redoing the entire epoxy floor?
- If I fix the
  crack, should I expect it to get worse every winter? (I live in MN)

Old Concrete (before repair)
[image]

New Concrete
[image]

Crack in Epoxy Floor
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the temperature swings in your location, it will be about impossible to prevent old and new concrete from cracking along joints. Those type of cracks are common. (I would be amazed if you didn't get cracks.)

I would contact the company that did the epoxy. Ask them if the crack is an issue and what they recommend if it is.  (A clear sealer possibly)